# CoffeeScript: Github ATOM, getSelection alternative for Atom API?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, atom-editor

If you want to get the user's selection on a webpage, you can use the window.getSelection() in your js file.

I am unable to find a similar method for github's atom. (in their API or something in coffeescript).

What can I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it.
We can use:
selection=editor.getSelection()
text=selection.getText()